# Strawberry Perl with mod_perl2: building Apache2 modules from CPAN

Tags: perl, mod-perl, mod-perl2, strawberry-perl, apache2-module

I have Strawberry Perl 5.10 and mod_perl2 installed per these [instructions on the mod_perl mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/perl-modperl/201007.mbox/%3CAANLkTimP1oCDwBU2RZ2hfK4nMorZ-SoZlJ_ennx8JKTT@mail.gmail.com%3E) without a problem.  However, trying to install various `Apache2::` modules that my scripts use result in errors.  One (`Apache2::Reload`) I was able to install despite this:

```
C:\>cpan -f Apache2::Reload
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.199)
Database was generated on Tue, 09 Nov 2010 02:40:29 GMT
Running install for module 'Apache2::Reload'
Running make for P/PH/PHRED/Apache-Reload-0.11.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.48)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.03)
Checksum for C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\P\PH\PHRED\Apache-Reload-0.11
.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.66)
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.40)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v2.36)

  CPAN.pm: Going to build P/PH/PHRED/Apache-Reload-0.11.tar.gz

Cannot opendir Y:\Apache\APACHE~2\lib: No such file or directory at C:/strawberr
y/perl/site/lib/Apache2/Build.pm line 1664.
Warning: No success on command[C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL]
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.71)
  PHRED/Apache-Reload-0.11.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install

C:\>
```

...just by copying a couple .pm files to `site/lib`.  However, the others I am less sure about.  For example, `Apache2::RequestRec` gives me the following errors:

```
C:\>cpan -f Apache2::RequestRec
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.199)
Database was generated on Tue, 09 Nov 2010 02:40:29 GMT
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v2.36)
Running install for module 'Apache2::RequestRec'
Running make for G/GO/GOZER/mod_perl-2.0.4.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.48)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.03)
Checksum for C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\G\GO\GOZER\mod_perl-2.0.4.tar
.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.66)
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v1.40)

  CPAN.pm: Going to build G/GO/GOZER/mod_perl-2.0.4.tar.gz

no conflicting prior mod_perl version found - good.

Next we need to know where the 'apxs' script is located. This script
provides a lot of information about the Apache installation, and makes
it easier to find things on your system. Normally it's located in the
same directory as the 'httpd' executable.

If you don't yet have Apache installed you can build Apache against
the Apache source code, but you won't be able to run the test suite (a
very important step). Therefore you may want to install Apache before
proceeding.


Please provide a full path to 'apxs' executable
(press Enter if you don't have it installed):


Please provide the location of the Apache directory:  C:\Program Files\Apache So
ftware Foundation\Apache2.2
[  error] Unable to open C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2/a
p_release.h: No such file or directory
[  error] Unable to determine server version, aborting.
[  error] Please specify MP_APXS or MP_AP_PREFIX.
Warning: No success on command[C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL]
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.71)
  GOZER/mod_perl-2.0.4.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install

C:\>
```

Is there some trick to compiling `Apache2::` modules under Strawberry Perl?  Do I need to compile my own Apache binaries too or something?  (If so, can I do that with the make tools supplied with Strawberry?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing via those instructions actually installs all the `Apache2::` modules, except for `Apache2::Reload`.

Comment: And Apache2::Reload is actually a pure-perl module, meaning that you can simply copy this file over to site\lib\Apache2\ and you'd be good: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PHRED/mod_perl-2.0.5/Apache-Reload/lib/Apache2/Reload.pm

Answer (score 1):

If you compile apache from source, you should have apxs.exe from apache.
Add that to `PATH`.  You need the apache source code for some `Apache::` bits.

Comment: This was a good lead, but there's no apxs.exe.  I got the apxs source and it's giving me heck under Windows with lots of missing files due to references to `/lib` that should probably be `\\bin`.  It remains to be seen if I can get it to compile.

Comment: The latest error it's giving me is `use MP_APR_CONFIG=/path/to/apr-config`, which I tried to set both on the command line with `cpan -f MP_APR...` and with `set MP_APR... && cpan -f Apache2::...`, neither of which worked.  The first fails because it tries to install `MP_APR_CONFIG=...` which is obviously not a module, and the second, well, I'm not sure where it's looking for the variable, but apparently the environment is not it.

Comment: I don't understand why mod_perl2 itself is so easy to install from CPAN, but all the `Apache2::` modules aren't...

Comment: Hmm...despite the fails here, it seems at some point the `Apache2::` modules all showed up in `site\lib`.  Must have a different problem that my convoluted mod_perl setup is making difficult to debug...